# checking if matrix columns are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, independence

according to the definition of linear dependency vectors $v_1,...,v_n$  are linearly independent $iff$ $c_1v_1$+$c_2v_2$+$...$+$c_nv_n≠0$. One can also do the gaussian elemination to get which columns are independent but i'm trying now the first method.

Let $A=\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
1 & 2 & 1  \\
0 & 3 & 2  \\
4 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 2 \end{array}\right]= \left[\begin{array}{r}0\\0\\0\\0\end{array}\right]$

The book states that  ${c_1-2c_2+3c_3=0}$, meaning that they are not linearly independent. How did they come out with the result, and namely how can one calculate it ? My head is going to blow! I cannot find a way to calculate it.

*($c_1$ is the 1$^{st}$ column , $c_2$ the 2$^{nd}$..)*

Comment: You should state that the $c$'s are non-zero.

Comment: In general,with a $n \times m$ matrix, you set up  $ k_1c_1+k_2c_2+...+k_m_c_m=0  $. Then you would have $n$ equations with $m$ unknowns. You would have $\sum k_i
\begin{vmatrix}
c_{i1}\\
c_{i2}\\
\vdots\\
\end{vmatrix}
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix $A$ has linearly independent columns if and only if $A$ has a trivial nullspace. Indeed, if 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
\vec c_1 & \dotsb & \vec c_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then the equation $A\vec x=\vec 0$ is equivalent to
$$
x_1\vec c_1+\dotsb+x_n\vec c_n=\vec 0
$$
Now, for your $A$ note that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1  \\
0 & 3 & 2  \\
4 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1/3\\
0 & 1 & 2/3 \\
0&0&0 \\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This tells us that $A\vec x=\vec 0$ if and only if
\begin{align*}
x_1 &= \frac{1}{3}\,x_3 & x_2 &= -\frac{2}{3}\,x_3
\end{align*}
Taking $x_3=3$ then gives your result.

Note, however that this linear combination is not unique.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try working out what $c_1-2c_2+3c_3$ is.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\ 
 0 \\ 
  4 \\
0\end{bmatrix}-2\begin{bmatrix}
2  \\ 
 3 \\ 
  2 \\
3\end{bmatrix}+3\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\ 
 2 \\ 
  0 \\
2\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1-2(2)+3(1)  \\ 
0-2(3)+3(2)  \\ 
4-2(2)+3(0)  \\
0-2(3)+3(2) \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0  \\ 
 0 \\ 
  0 \\
0\end{bmatrix}$$

How did we find $c_1-2c_2+3c_3$? Let's write $\alpha c_1 +\beta c_2 + \gamma c_3 = 0$. Then we get:

$$\alpha+2\beta+\gamma=0$$
$$3\beta+2\gamma=0$$
$$4\alpha + 2\beta = 0$$

Subtracting the third equation from the first, we get $-3\alpha+\gamma=0$. Now just pick a value for your $\alpha$ (say $1$), and you find that $\gamma=3$. Then substituting into the second equation, you find $\beta=-2$

Comment: He asks for a way to come to the result, from what I understood.

Comment: Upon re-reading the question, you're probably right

Comment: thanks for answering. But i have already understand the combination.I'm asking hower how to come to the result

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the question now to answer that

Comment: Edited. Let me know if anything's unclear

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an "for every $c_1, c_2,... \in R$"
This means, that every solution which gives you zero vector proofs dependency.

And one solution is $v_1-2v_2+3v_3=0$, the $c$s are the scalars.

How to calculate that:
The second row tells you, that $3 c_2 +2c_3 =0$ and the third $4c_1+2c_2=0$.
So just pick one of the $c$s and calculate the rest.
Hint: try $c_1=1$.:)

Comment: try 4 & 2 for the first row. i doesn't work

Comment: You have to pick exactly one of the three and calculate the other two with those equations.

Answer (score 0):

Since we have that rank $A = 2$ (every $3\times 3$ determinant is equal to zero and there exists at least one $2 \times 2$ determinant not equal to zero), it is clear that the vectors $c_1, c_2, c_3$ are linearly dependent. Thus, we have:
$$\begin{array}[t]{l}c_1 = a c_2 + b c_3\\\\
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 4 \\0 
\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} 2a \\ 3a \\ 2a \\ 3a\end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix} b \\ 2b \\ 0 \\2b \end{bmatrix}
\\
\end{array}$$
So:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}  2a = 4\\[2ex] 3a + 2b = 0  \end{array}\right. \implies a = 2 \text{ and } b = -3,$$
which means:
$c_1 = 2c_2 - 3c_2$.